# Smarty: как компилировать шаблон сразу (registerPlugin)?

Tags: php, smarty

В шаблоне код:

```
{test} 
{$test} 
{/test}
```

на php

```
$smarty->registerPlugin("block","test", "test");
```

теперь функция:

```
function test ($params, $content, $smarty, &$repeat, $template = ''){ 
 $smarty->assign('test', 1); 
 echo $content; 
 $smarty->assign('test', 2); 
 echo $content; 
 $smarty->assign('test', 3); 
 echo $content; 
}
```

и выводит все это дело:

333

а хотелось бы 123.

Подскажите пожалуйста. Я понимаю, что `$smarty->assign` задает переменную, которая только потом компилируется в шаблон, а вот что мне сделать, чтобы шаблон сразу компилировался? Вот например функция `{foreach $array as $arr}значение {$arr}{/foreach}` правильно выводит, перебирает массив. И мне надо что-то вроде этого.

Comment: Или может как посмотреть что по сути в $content?
Если бы там была строка $test, то вместо $smarty->assign можно было бы просто задавать переменную $test = 1; Но так не работает, видимо там переменная называется по другому. Вот как узнать название?

Comment: В общем грубо говоря $smarty->display() компилирует файл, а мне бы принудительно скомпилировать то, что находится в переменной $content.

Comment: Ну думаю не обязательно использовать fetch(), может как-то п-другому обойтись? Как на php задать эту переменную $test перед echo $content; вместо $smarty->assign? Точнее как ее найти? Не могла же она испариться, просто название скорее всего поменялось.